# Generating Relative cyclic sequence of numbers in php?

Tags: php, laravel, math, numbers

I want to generate two sequence of numbers. I have two parameters.

**First**: value can be any number between 1-12 inclusive.

**Second**: value can be any number between 1-12 inclusive.

Example,

first: 10,
second: 3,

Then, for above parameters I want two arrays with values like below,

```
10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5  6  7  8 9

3  4  5  6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2
```

**Update :** I need a function that takes the two numbers as parameter and output like above arrays.

Is there any simple way to achieve this ? I'm using php and laravel.

Comment: what are you trying to achive and what is your expecet output

Comment: @Manojkiran. I've updated my question

Comment: if you are passing the parameter as `(5,10)`  then Your expected  output is first array `[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4]` and second array as `[10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` **Am i making it Clear**

Comment: @Manojkiran.A Yes

Comment: i have added my answer check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this func:

```
function transform($array, int $start) {
    while ($array[0] != $start) {
       $number = array_shift($array);
       $array[] = $number;
    }

    return $array;
}

$first = transform(range(1, 12), 10);
$second = transform(range(1, 12), 3);
```

Comment: It gives 0 in the array as well, I don't want that number in the array. I need number from 1 to 12 only

Comment: @SagarGautam use range(1, 12) instead if range(0, 12)

Answer (score 1):

As per your input, I have created the function

```
function generateArrayRange($parameterOne='')
{
    //mimiminum number in array
    $minumumNumber = 1;
    //maximum number array  number in array
    $maximumNumber =12;
    //getting the first part of array
    $firstArrayDummyFirst = range($parameterOne, $maximumNumber);
    //getting the second  part of array
    $firstArrayDummySecond = range($minumumNumber, $parameterOne-1);
    //merging both to the single array 
    $parmOneArray = array_merge($firstArrayDummyFirst,$firstArrayDummySecond);
    //returing the generated array with unique
    return ($parmOneArray);
}
```

Your input may be  `print_r(generateArrayRange(10));`

Then the result will be

`Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 11 [2] => 12 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 [5] => 3 [6] => 4 [7] => 5 [8] => 6 [9] => 7 [10] => 8 [11] => 9 )`

Your input may be  `print_r(generateArrayRange(3));`

Then the result will be

`Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 [6] => 9 [7] => 10 [8] => 11 [9] => 12 [10] => 1 [11] => 2 )`

> BUT YOU WANT TO PASS SECOND PARAMETER

So try this function:

```
function transformToarray(int $parameterOne,int $parameterTwo = null)
{
    //mimiminum number in array
    $minumumNumber = 1;
    //maximum number array  number in array
    $maximumNumber =12;

    //getting the first part of array
    $firstArrayDummyFirst = range($parameterOne, $maximumNumber);
    //getting the second  part of array
    $firstArrayDummySecond = range($minumumNumber, $parameterOne-1);
    //merging both to the single array 
    $parmOneArray = array_merge($firstArrayDummyFirst,$firstArrayDummySecond);
    //returing the generated array with unique

    if (!empty($parameterTwo) || !is_null($parameterTwo) || $parameterTwo != "" ) 
    {  
       //getting the first part of array
        $secondArrayDummyFirst = range($parameterTwo, $maximumNumber);
        //getting the second  part of array
        $secondArrayDummySecond = range($minumumNumber, $parameterTwo-1);
        //merging both to the single array 
        $parmTwoArray = array_merge($secondArrayDummyFirst,$secondArrayDummySecond);
        //returing the generated array with unique

        return compact('parmOneArray','parmTwoArray');
    }
    return $parmOneArray;
}
```

PHP Fiddle

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/chkx-qt4i

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range`:

```
$first = 5;
$firstArray = range(1,12);
for ($i = 1; $i < $first; $i++) {
    $firstArray[11] = array_shift($firstArray);
}
var_dump($firstArray);
```

and you do the same with the array.

For the function:

```
function shiftedArray($int)
{
    $int = $int % 12;
    $array = range(1,12);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $int; $i++) {
        $array[11] = array_shift($array);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Just call it twice:

```
$firstArray = shiftedArray(10);
$secondArray = shiftedArray(3);
```

Comment: you're welcome, you will notice it accepts values greater than 12 too. @SagarGautam

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = 3;
$second = 10;
$limit = 12;

$count = 1;
$out1 = $first;


while($out1 <= $limit){

    if($out1 == $limit){
        echo $out1 . " ";

        while($count < $first){
            echo $count . " ";
            $count++;
        }

    }else{
        echo $out1 . " ";
    }
    $out1++;
}
echo "<br>";
$count = 1;
$out1 = $second;
while($out1 <= $limit){

    if($out1 == $limit){
        echo $out1 . " ";

        while($count < $second){
            echo $count . " ";
            $count++;
        }

    }else{
        echo $out1 . " ";
    }
    $out1++;
}
```